# I want to automate postgresql commands in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

When I execute following command:

```
kubectl exec -it odoo-db-0 -n newnisa -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -c 'create user odoo with password 'Pappaya@2020';'"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Pappaya"
LINE 1: create user odoo with password Pappaya@2020;
                                   ^
```

Please help me on this

Comment: Unbalance and or unescaped quotes in your expression.

Comment: You might consider using `kubectl port-forward` to open a temporary connection to the database, then use `psql` directly on your local system.  That would avoid the multiple levels of quoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to create a user:

```
kubectl exec -it odoo-db-0 -n newnisa -- psql -U postgres -c "create user odoo with password 'Pappaya@2020'";
```

You can check created users:

```
$\du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 odoo      |                                                            | {}
```